# Is it possible to use "Run With Coverage" in IntelliJ without a test?

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, code-coverage

I'm working with IntelliJ 2020.3. Coverage is working fine for our Unit Tests.
But I want to have a running Spring Boot Application, then call some rest calls against my local machine and see the coverage. But that’s not working, coverage dialog is showing but its 0% for everything.

Is it possible to run the coverage not for a test?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the solution:
It's not working if you just stop the server. You have to use exit it.

[image]